# Move a pixel with arrow keys in assembly

Tags: assembly, graphics, x86-16, tasm, dosbox

This is the code:

```
IDEAL
MODEL small
STACK 100h
DATASEG
; --------------------------
key db 0
locH dw 0  ;location horizontal
locV dw 0  ;location vertical
; --------------------------
CODESEG

UP_ON equ 48h
UP_OFF equ 0c8h
DOWN_ON equ 50h
DOWN_OFF equ 0d0h
LEFT_ON equ 4Bh
LEFT_OFF equ 0cBh
RIGHT_ON equ 4Dh
RIGHT_OFF equ 0cDh
ESCAPE equ 1

proc getKey
in al, 60h
mov [key],al
ret
endp getKey

start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
; --------------------------
;fullscreen
MOV AL, 13H
MOV AH, 0
INT 10H
;print red pixel
MOV AH,0Ch
MOV AL,4
MOV CX,160 ; 0 ≤ X ≤ 319
MOV DX,100 ; 0 ≤ Y ≤ 199
INT 10H
mov [locH],cx
mov [locV],dx

mainLoop:
call getKey
cmp [key],ESCAPE
jne next
jmp exit
next:
;checks if key is up
cmp [key],UP_ON
je up
;checks if key is down
cmp [key],DOWN_ON 
je down
;checks if key is left
cmp [key],LEFT_ON 
je left
;checks if key is right
cmp [key],RIGHT_ON 
jne next2
jmp right
next2:
jmp mainLoop
; --------------------------    

exit:
;exits full screen mode
MOV AL, 3H
MOV AH, 0
INT 10H
mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h

up:
;delete previous red pixel
MOV AH,0Ch
MOV AL,0
MOV CX,[locH] ; 0 ≤ X ≤ 319
MOV DX,[locV] ; 0 ≤ Y ≤ 199
INT 10H
inc [locV]
;print next red pixel
MOV AH,0Ch
MOV AL,4
MOV CX,[locH] ; 0 ≤ X ≤ 319
MOV DX,[locV] ; 0 ≤ Y ≤ 199
INT 10H

mov [locH],cx
mov [locV],dx

jmp mainLoop



down:
;delete previous red pixel
MOV AH,0Ch
MOV AL,0
MOV CX,[locH] ; 0 ≤ X ≤ 319
MOV DX,[locV] ; 0 ≤ Y ≤ 199
INT 10H
dec [locV]
;print next red pixel
MOV AH,0Ch
MOV AL,4
MOV CX,[locH] ; 0 ≤ X ≤ 319
MOV DX,[locV] ; 0 ≤ Y ≤ 199
INT 10H

mov [locH],cx
mov [locV],dx



left:
;delete previous red pixel
MOV AH,0Ch
MOV AL,0
MOV CX,[locH]; 0 ≤ X ≤ 319
MOV DX,[locV] ; 0 ≤ Y ≤ 199
INT 10H
dec [locH]
;print next red pixel
MOV AH,0Ch
MOV AL,4
MOV CX,[locH] ; 0 ≤ X ≤ 319
MOV DX,[locV] ; 0 ≤ Y ≤ 199
INT 10H

mov [locH],cx
mov [locV],dx


right:
;delete previous red pixel
MOV AH,0Ch
MOV AL,0
MOV CX,[locH]; 0 ≤ X ≤ 319
MOV DX,[locV] ; 0 ≤ Y ≤ 199
INT 10H
inc [locH]
;print next red pixel
MOV AH,0Ch
MOV AL,4
MOV CX,[locH] ; 0 ≤ X ≤ 319
MOV DX,[locV] ; 0 ≤ Y ≤ 199
INT 10H

mov [locH],cx
mov [locV],dx
jmp mainLoop



END start
```

It seems that there are two problems in the code:

1. Relative jump out of range by 000Eh bytes.-**SOLVED**
2. The code doesn't work properly. When I press an arrow key the pixel just freaks out and moves to a different place on screen.
   I have no idea why there are problems and I tried everything I could think off.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: For the first issue add the directive `JUMPS` to the beginning of the source. TASM will automagically change the wrong jump in a sequence of two correct jumps (one relative and one absolute).

Comment: @rkhb Sorry, I don't get it. How can I do it?

Comment: @Emil - The solution for an out of range jump is to change, for example, `je exit` into a longer sequence `jne next / jmp exit / next:`. Apparently TASM can do this for you, if you ask it to.

Comment: For your second problem, I suspect that saving `cx` and `dx` *after* the interrupt is saving some random values. Generally registers are not preserved thru calls.

Comment: @BoPersson Thanks, the first problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're left with your second problem, here are some observations about the current program:

- You should not find out about keypresses by directly reading some keyboard port. Better use the appropriate BIOS function:

  ```
  proc getKey
      mov ah, 00h
      int 10h
      mov [key],al
      ret
  endp getKey
  ```
- When the user presses the *UP* key, he will expect the red dot to move upwards on the screen. Since the coordinates system for the screen is different from the usual mathematical XY-coordinates system, you need to `dec [locV]` in the *up* routine and `inc [locV]` in the *down* routine.
  Your *left* and *right* routines are correct.
- A reason why BIOS calls might fail is when not all the arguments are provided!
  The BIOS calls to plot a pixel expect the display page in the `BH` register. You should set this to zero:

  ```
  mov bh, 0  ;Display page
  ```